# C++ variadic templates with repeating types

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Is it possible to write variadic templates or fold expressions where the function signature can be something like

```cpp
void f(int, string, int, string, ...)
```

That style is very popular and user-friendly in python, but I couldn't get it to work in C++. In particular I would use it to feed a plotting function with data followed by a label for example.

edit: to expand, I would like to call the function like this:

```cpp
f(5, "first number");
f(5, "first number", 6, "second number");
```

and with 4, 6 or ... 2*n parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a variadic function like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void f(int data, string const &label, Ts&&... rest)
{
  process(data, label);
  f(std::forward<Ts>(rest...));
}
```

with a base case:

```
void f() {}
```

to terminate the recursion.

Now only calls of the form:

```
f(1, "hi");           // ok
f(1, "hi", 2, "bye"); // ok
// etc
```

will compile, whereas:

```
f(1);          // error
f("hi");       // error
f(1, "hi", 2); // error
```

will not.

Comment: This asks for perfect forwarding, or at least `const` references.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, define two overloads:

```cpp
void f() {}

template<class... Ts>
void f(int i, std::string s, Ts... ts) {
    f(std::move(ts)...); // static recursion
}
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok, sorry, not here, but in more complicated cases the compiler is easily buffled.